# Audit trail with MySql

Tags: mysql, audit-trail

I need to make sure that any change to my SQL database is logged for specific tables.

An interesting solution is here:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/Transaction%20time%20validity%20in%20MySQL.pdf

However, it was published in 2012. Have things changed since then?
Are there better tools today to keep track of changes automatically with MySql?

Merc.

Comment: you can create trigger.

Comment: The article linked talked specifically about using triggers... I am not sure your comment makes any sense.